# Schedule Expression

Tags: junit, ejb, mockito, schedule

I am trying to create a Junit test for a method which includes ScheduleExpression. I have tried to use PowerMockito to mock it but I continue to get a error message which reads

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method 
that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ejb/ScheduleExpression
```

Here is how I am using PowerMockito

```
 ScheduleExpression expression = PowerMockito.mock(ScheduleExpression.class);
```

I have tried the annotations

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Static.class)
```

but they didn't work.

I have also tried Mockito version 1.9.5 but I get the same error. Am I missing a pom dependency?

Is there a way to Mock the ScheduleExpression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the name of the class you want PowerMock to prepare for...

`@PrepareForTest(ScheduleExpression.class)`

However, in your case I don't see the need to use PowerMock because `ScheduleExpression` is not final, or has private or static methods you may be trying to mock.

Try just using vanilla Mockito instead of PowerMockito like this...

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
...
ScheduleExpression expression = Mockito.mock(ScheduleExpression.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sadly it did not resolve my issue. I think it may be caused by a missing Maven Dependence.

Comment: If you follow my advice of just using `MockitoJUnitRunner` the only dependencies you need are [junit](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22junit%22%20AND%20a%3A%22junit%22) and [mockito-all](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.mockito%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mockito-all%22). I tested mocking `ScheduleExpression` myself.

Comment: Not sure must be a environment issue as it is working in another project. Thanks you the help